# How to track origin in Hyperledger fabric UTXO tokens

Tags: token, hyperledger-fabric

I have a question related to Hyperledger fabric blockchain data model. I need to handle two types of objects, and for each one of them I'll probably need a separate smart contract to load the data related to each type of object, and handle that data.

For instance, lets say I need a smart contract to handle tokens that represent pencils, so that they can be transferred from one account to another. And lets say that I also need a separate smart contract to handle the trees that were involved in the creation of the pencils, because first I need to process the data about the trees, to later issue the corresponding UTXO-tokens in the channel.

Lets suppose that, for every tree that is added into the blockchain, 100 pencil tokens should be issued.

I'm going to be using the UTXO token provided by Hyperledger fabric in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/token-utxo to handle the pencil tokens, which already provides functions to "mint" and "transfer" tokens, but I need some insight in how to relate the logic between this smart contract and the contract to process the trees in the ledger. It would be ideal to stablish a way of tracking the pencil tokens, providing a functionality to proof that they were created from a particular tree.

Any information or tips on how to do this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UTXO model is used for tracking fungible tokens, that is, tokens that are identical and interchangeable. If you want to track the source of your pencils, then they are not identical and interchangeable, so you should instead consider a non-fungible token model where each asset can have unique properties. For example each pencil could have a unique identifier (key) with a set of JSON properties (value), where the source tree is one of the JSON properties. See the asset transfer samples for ideas around modeling and tracking non-fungible assets with properties.